# Downloading most recent Image from server in image view in android app

Tags: java, android, image

I am a newbie and as soon as I started learning the language I got one project. Most of it is done but I am strugglig in a basic programming problem. My app is supposed to provide the images of the price lists set by the commissioner in our city by downloadin from thir original website. The problem is after every few days a new image appears as new prices are set and the image's url in my app becomes obsolete. the new image that appears on the website does not have a ur that follow a pattern like image1,2,3 but it is a random number every time. Can someone please help me how can I solve this problem of mine?

PS. I know how to get an image in the imageView. All I want is to make the app smart enough to download the most recently added image every time. Please please respond. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could search the image URL from the website using an html parser like Jsoup and then load the image into an imageview using the Picasso or Glide library

Comment: Can you pls be more specific or share any link that can explain what exactly a html parser does?

Comment: It lets you extract data from a webpage using its HTML structure. http://jsoup.org/  With this you could find where the image link is in the webpage structure and then use an image loading library to load the image into an ImageView.